# Nullpointer with gettext and editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, gettext, tostring

I'm new with that and I've searching all the day to resolve it, could you help me?

I'm trying to get in a String a `EditText` I've set in an `AlertDialog`

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View alert = li.inflate(R.layout.alert, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder addUser = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        addUser.setView(alert);
        addUser.setTitle("...");
        addUser.setMessage("...");
        addUser.setCancelable(false);
        addUser.setPositiveButton(R.string.btNext, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Final EditText getName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inUsName);
        String uName = getName.getText().toString(); //NullPointerException
                acept(v);
            }
        });
        addUser.setNegativeButton(R.string.btCancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                cancel();
            }
        });
        addUser.show();
    }
```

}

The `EditText` ID is correct and I have all the components in alert.xml (not the activity default xml).

Do you find something wrong ? I'm sure its a not an optimized or well-formed code (its my first android try).

Thanks so much.

Comment: Can I assume `Final EditText` is supposed to be `final EditText` and is an error in your post? Either way `Final EditText getName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inUsName);` is trying to get the edit text with the id inUsName from your Dialog view, not your main layout view. That is why it returns null.

Comment: use `dialog.findByView` (or `alert.findByView`, with alert being declared final)

Comment: I also try it but same problem, i get method cannot be resolved findViewById(int)

Comment: At the end with

    final EditText getName = (EditText) alert.findViewById(R.id.inUsName);
                    String uName = getName.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println(uName);

and

    final View alert = li.inflate(R.layout.alert, null);

Thanks to all guys ! You get it in a minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Change this code. You have to provide inflater.findviewbyId just like in fragments :

```
Final EditText getName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inUsName);
```

To this:

```
final EditText getName = (EditText) li.findViewById(R.id.inUsName);
```

Comment: I have tryed that before, i get this error with findViewById() "method cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 1):

Check for the `null` value.

```
final EditText getName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.inUsName);
String uName = getName.getText()!=null? getName.getText().toString(): null;
```

Comment: the null is not coming from this

Comment: yes your point is correct null value is coming because getName is null. I have edited the answer.

Comment: unrelated to the question. The point stands that the view is not found. preventing the app to crash only hide the issue under the carpet.

Comment: if i use li.(layoute inflated) before findViewById() i get an error

Comment: use dialog.findViewById(R.id.inUsName);

Answer (score 0):

if EditText is on the Layout activity_add you must create

```
Final EditText getName;
```

add getname at activity

```
getname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inUsName);
```

then add String to AlertDialog

```
String uName = getName.getText().toString();
```

or

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");
// Create TextView
final TextView input = new TextView (this);
String uName = getName.getText().toString();
input.setText(uName);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Do something with value!
  }
});

  alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      // Canceled.
  }
});
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Edittext is not in part of view alert which you have inflated 
use

```
 Final EditText getName = (EditText)alert.findViewById(R.id.inUsName);
 getName.getText().toString();// will not give nullpoint exception
```

instead of

```
 Final EditText getName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inUsName);
```